# BaseAdapter selecting item and processing issue

Tags: android, android-listview, inflate, baseadapter, android-adapter

I have a `ListView` which extends `BaseAdapter`. I have a data[] array. The `ListView` inflates and populates correctly. What I am trying to do is make a `ImageView` visible on the list item (basically a check image on the right side of the inflated view) when the user selects the item and if there was a previous item selected, I just hide that `ImageView`. This works fine too.

But after I select a new item and scroll back and forth I see weird behavior, the check image is sometimes visible in multiple list items or is hidden in the actual item that is currently selected. Could someone please help and explain what I am doing wrong?

I have these two lines in the `onCreate` method:

```
    adap = new EfficientAdapter(this);
    lstview.setAdapter(adap);
```

and the adapter code:

```
public static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
  private LayoutInflater mInflater;
  private Context context;
  private ImageView CurrentSelectedImageView;
  private Integer CurrentPosition = 14;


  public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
  }


  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    //Log.e("TAG",String.valueOf(position));

    if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adaptor_content, null);

      holder = new ViewHolder();
      holder.textLine = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCategoryCaption);
      holder.iconLine = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iconLine);
      holder.imgCheckbox = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgCheck);


      //If the CurrentPosition == position then make the checkbox visible else dont.
      if (CurrentPosition == position){

        holder.imgCheckbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }else{
        holder.imgCheckbox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      }


      final ImageView Checkbox = holder.imgCheckbox;

      //Now if the list item is clicked then set the position as the current item and make the checkbox visible.

      convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        private int pos = position;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (CurrentSelectedImageView!=null){
                CurrentSelectedImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            Checkbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            CurrentSelectedImageView = Checkbox;
            CurrentPosition = pos;

        }
      });

      convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
      holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


        int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("nodeinsert", "drawable", context.getString(R.string.package_str));
        if (id != 0x0) {
          mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), id);
        }

        holder.iconLine.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);
        holder.textLine.setText(String.valueOf(data[position]));


    if (CurrentPosition == position){
        Log.e("TAG",CurrentPosition + "---" + String.valueOf(position));
        holder.imgCheckbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        holder.imgCheckbox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }


    return convertView;
  }



  static class ViewHolder {
    TextView textLine;
    ImageView iconLine;
    ImageView imgCheckbox;
  }

  @Override
  public Filter getFilter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.length;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data[position];
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But after I select a new item and scroll back and forth I see wierd
>   behavior, the check image is sometimes visible in multiple list items
>   or is hidden in the actual item that is currently selected.

That's most likely happening because of the way you set the click listener for `convertView`. You set the `OnCLickListener` only for the case when `convertView` is `null` but as you scroll the `ListView` up and down, rows will get recycled and you would end up with the same listener as other rows.

Anyway if you just want to have only one row with the image visible there is a much simpler way to do it. First of all you should drop the `OnCLickListener` on the `convertView` and use the `OnItemClickListener` on your `ListView` element. From this listener callback you'll modify the rows:

```
lstview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position,
                    long id) {
                View oldView = l.getChildAt(adap.getSelectedPosition());
                ImageView img;
                if (oldView != null && adap.getSelectedPosition() != -1) {
                    img = (ImageView) oldView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                    img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                adap.setSelectedPosition(position);
            }
        });
```

Then modify the adapter like this:

```
// a field in the adapter
private int mSelectedPosition = -1;

// getter and setter methods for the field above
public void setSelectedPosition(int selectedPosition) {
    mSelectedPosition = selectedPosition;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public int getSelectedPosition() {
    return mSelectedPosition;
}

// and finally your getView() method
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adaptor_content, parent, false);
      holder = new ViewHolder();
      holder.textLine = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCategoryCaption);
      holder.iconLine = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iconLine);
      holder.imgCheckbox = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgCheck);
      convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
      holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    if (mSelectedPosition == position) {
    holder.imgCheckbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
    holder.imgCheckbox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }     
      // what is the point of this call?!
      // you should move this to another place(like the adapter's constructor), the getIdentifier()
      // method is a bit slow and you call it each time the adapter calls getView()
      // you should never use it in the getView() method(), especially as all you do is get the id of the same drawable again and again
      int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("nodeinsert", "drawable", context.getString(R.string.package_str));
      // ?!?
      if (id != 0x0) {
          mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), id);
      }
      holder.iconLine.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);
      holder.textLine.setText(String.valueOf(data[position]));
      return convertView;
}
```

Comment: @lumpawire You could have done it with a listener on the `convertView` but in your particular case it's easier like I shown you. With your code you inflate the `convertView` and set a listener on it **only** when `convertView` is `null`(most likely when the list is first shown). But, as you scroll the `ListView` down, `convertView` isn't null(at this time you don't inflate a new `convertView` and also you don't set a new listener, you have the old one). The problem is that this old listener is(or could be) pointing to the wrong `ImageView` so you end up with the wrong behavior.

Comment: @lumpawire For example, try(I don't guarantee that it will work) to set the listener after the `convertView` `if`-`else` clause(for `null`). Also your approach is not recommended as you hold on to views to identify the one you want and this is a little difficult(well, not that difficult but it should be avoided) to handle in a recycling `View`.